# What's the difference between Eclipse Milo Stack vs SDK and what is the session manager?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I am trying to understand the eclipse milo package and I am confused on what the difference is between the stack and the sdk. In addition, I am looking for an overall general breakdown of the files/classes in the package. What is the sessionmanager used for? If I were to implement an LDS, should I mainly focus on using the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The stack provides a lot of the "basics" of the spec like transports, serialization, data structures, and security. It sets up a framework for the the implementation of the OPC UA services but does not implement them.

The SDK is focused on providing higher level implementations of those services. The `SessionManager` is an internal implementation detail that isn't meant for use by users of the SDK.

If you were to build an LDS you'd really only need the stack and then to implement the Discovery service set. It's a non-trivial effort.

Comment: My goal is to eventually create a discovery server (LDS) application which OPC UA Servers can register to and clients can connect to. You mentioned I only need the stack. Does that mean I implement the DiscoveryServiceSet interface defined in the stack in the SDK? If so, how would I create a demo LDS server?

Comment: Yes, you'd implement that interface. You need to read OPC UA Parts 4 and 12 very carefully and figure out how an LDS works. I can't help you and I don't have an example for you.

Comment: I read part 4 and 12 and I have a good understanding of the process behind LDS. However, I am kind of confused on how to implement it with Milo. I understand I would implement that interface but I am not sure how someone would go about creating a discovery server after that. There are a lot of classes and I pretty much lost in trying to connect each of them together. Could you please suggest some classes I might need to build an LDS or give me a direction? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think you want to look at `UaStackServer` and its `addServiceSet` methods.

Comment: It looks like UaStackServer already implements the DiscoveryServiceSet interface. Although it doesn't implement RegisterServer. Are the already implemented discovery services only for the UA Servers alone and not the discovery servers (since if there's one server, it is its own LDS)? I'm guessing I would have to implement the RegisterServer service by extending that class?

Comment: It implements a basic DiscoveryServiceSet that is suitable for a "normal" OPC UA server. I think the one you'd implement for an LDS would look different, and you'd need implementations for `onFindServersOnNetwork`, `onRegisterServer`, and `onRegisterServer2`. Copying some of the code from `onGetEndpoints` might be possible. You won't be able to extend the implementation you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the replies Kevin. I really appreciate you helping. I just had some more questions. So essentially, I implement the interface DiscoveryServiceSet which will be completely different from the one implemented inside UaStackServer since the default is for a normal OPC UA Server. Then I will add those services using the addServiceSet(in this case UaStackServer seems to already have added the DiscoveryServiceSet). What happens afterwards? How would I create an LDS out of this? Would I mimic the example in milo or the demo server in kotlin? How would you write a regular ua server vs LDS?

Comment: Your instance of `UaStackServer` with the service set added and then `startup()` called _is_ a server. You may need some additional services implemented as well for a bare minimum LDS, I'm not sure. A normal OPC UA server would use `OpcUaServer` from the SDK instead, but that gives you a bunch of extra stuff you may not need as an LDS like sessions and subscriptions. It may turn out you need to be doing something like the `OpcUaServer` implementation from the SDK but more minimal, because e.g. you probably need to have the standard OPC UA address space present even for an LDS.

Comment: Do I need to implement onGetEndpoints for an LDS? Why is the regular onGetEndpoints implemented in the DefaultDiscoveryServiceSet not enough?